# Is it possible to run lion, ubuntu, and backtrack on my imac?

Tags: unix, macos

Would it be possible to do this? To run lion, ubuntu, and backtrack all on the same machine?
Or even just lion and backtrack would do the trick. If so, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Sounds like a Question for SuperUser.com.

Comment: Possibly, but how exactly is that a programming question? :-)

Comment: of course. you need a grub bootloader and separate partitions. this isn't the forum for these types of questions though. you want to try a different forum, maybe super users xchange.

Answer (score 1):

It will be easiest to run Ubuntu and Backtrack in virtual machines rather than setting up a multiple boot configuration, and you'll be able to run everything simultaneously (assuming enough RAM). You'll need a copy of Parallels or VMware Fusion (which cost money) or VirtualBox (which doesn't).

Answer (score 0):

The [Ubuntu MacTel Community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation) should be able to get you started. It admittedly fails to cover a "Mac OS X with multi Linux" install, but once your HD is partitioned and rEFIt is up and running, I think it should be fairly straightforward to get both distros installed (well, at least "straightforward" by Linux standards).